# Addition to "numpy" array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have b_x as an array and I'm operating on it as shown in code.

```
G = 5
b_x =numpy.array([[0] for i in range(G)])
print(b_x)

for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        b_x[x] += y*0.25
        print("y*0.25:" + " " + str(y*0.25))
        print("b_x[x]:" + " " + str(b_x[x][0]))
    print("end")
print(b_x)
```

After addition my b_x should be like:

```
[[2.5]
 [2.5]
 [2.5]
 [2.5]
 [2.5]]
```

But the output is different.So, I added some print statements to check, and got the following output:

```
[[0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]]
y*0.25: 0.0
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.25
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.5
b_x[x]: 0  
y*0.25: 0.75
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 1.0
b_x[x]: 1
end
y*0.25: 0.0
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.25
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.5
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.75
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 1.0
b_x[x]: 1 
end
y*0.25: 0.0
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.25
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.5
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.75
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 1.0
b_x[x]: 1
end
y*0.25: 0.0
b_x[x]: 0 
y*0.25: 0.25
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.5
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.75
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 1.0
b_x[x]: 1
end
y*0.25: 0.0
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.25
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.5
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 0.75
b_x[x]: 0
y*0.25: 1.0
b_x[x]: 1  
end
[[1] 
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]
```

I n the end, every value is 1 which is wrong. And on checking the inner print statement it seems that the elements don't get added when the (y*0.25) value is a decimal.
I have checked another code where if the value to be added is 12.5, only 12 gets added to the array element.Why does this happen with numpy array?

The problem doesn't occur with list(if I define b_x as a list), there the decimal values get added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
b_x =numpy.array([[0] for i in range(G)])
```

to

```
b_x =numpy.array([[0.0] for i in range(G)])
```

or better

```
b_x =numpy.zeros((5,))
```

The trouble is that in your version `b` is stored as integers, so `b[x] += (some smallish fraction)` gets rounded down to 0.